# JQuery or Underscore equivalent to JavaScript's hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Take the following array of objects:

```
var array = [
{
  name: 'joe',
  job: 'jack in the box',
  age: 28,
},
{
  name: 'john',
  job: 'mcdonalds',
  age: 34,
},
{
  name: 'frank',
  job: 'wendys',
}
];
```

I have a function I wrote out to find the averages of the ages in both JavaScript and underscore.  However, first I need to tell the function that if the "age" property doesn't exist, then assign that person the age of 0 before entering the function, otherwise you will get a NaN.

So, here is how I do that in JavaScript, and it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!array[i].hasOwnProperty('age')) {
        array[i].age = 0;
    }
};
```

Now, I am trying to do the same thing, but only using jQuery and Underscore.

I have tried using underscore's inArray(), but it seems that this only finds whether an index is in an array, and in this case I need to see if there is a property within an object, that are themselves the indexes of the array.

**Note: I am new to this and trying to learn, please do not provide the full answer, but instead maybe a concept or reference to the method that I can research on my own.

Thanks!!**

Comment: What you say you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. Neither jQuery nor Underscore provide a way to do that *precisely because* the native JavaScript runtime already provides `.hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: I don't know why someone want to use something of `jquery` when you can just say `!array[i].hasOwnProperty('age')` or `!array[i].age`.

Comment: Vanilla JS has also [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method. When cached, it's probably faster than `hasOwnProperty` (which at least in some browsers is extremely slow).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`_.has`](http://underscorejs.org/#has) when you need a safe reference to `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if (!_.has(array[i], 'age')) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @zzzzBov, but real quick, anytime I'm running _. I am getting an error that _ is undefined, I assume this means I need to put a link in the head of my html document that will be the source for underscore, do you know where i can get that link? i cant seem to find it anywhere, thanks!

Comment: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

`hasOwnProperty` is available in vanilla JS and is beautiful, `JQuery` and `underscore` might not have an implementation because there is no need for a simpler wrapper for that.